# Magento 2 custom indexer - How to execute related indexers

Tags: magento2, indexer

i have a custom módule with his own indexer. I need that when i execute it (indexer:reindex custom_index), some indexes runs after.

There is an example with the "catalogrule_rule" indexer.

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogrule_rule
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:45
```

Here is my mview.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd">
<view id="custom_index" class="My\Module\Model\Indexer\CustomIndexer" group="indexer">
    <subscriptions>
        <table name="custom_table" entity_column="entity_id" />
    </subscriptions>
</view>
```

Here is my indexer.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
<indexer id="custom_index" view_id="custom_index" class="My\Module\Model\Indexer\CustomIndexer" shared_index="custom_index">
    <title translate="true">Custom indexer</title>
    <description translate="true">Custom description</description>
</indexer>
<indexer id="catalogrule_rule">
    <dependencies>
        <indexer id="custom_index" />
    </dependencies>
</indexer>
```

But, when i run setup:upgrade, i find this error...

```
Module 'Magento_Eav':
Module 'Magento_Directory':
Module 'Magento_Customer':
Module 'Magento_Theme':
Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...Invalid Document 
Element 'title': This element is not expected.
Line: 10
```

Comment: I think you have problem in another xml file :)